# Image Aspect Ratio

Tags: image, silverlight, grid, windows-phone-8

I have a grid system on my silverlight windows phone 8 page which will accommodate a number of pics on a button click. The size of the cells assigned to be 150x100.

My question is, if the original image size is 1000x1500, it will get squished in the grid, as the aspect ratio will be different. Is there a way to handle this, below is the code that i have written. Please tell me what change i have to do in the code.

Note: i am using a scale transform and assigning ScaleX and ScaleY as 1.

```
public resizeImage(Image img)
{
     double originalHeight = 500;
     double originalWidth  = 1000;
     double originalAspectRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight;

      if (img.Width < originalWidth || img.Height < originalHeight)
      {
            // no change has to be done
            PageScale.ScaleX = 1.0;
            PageScale.ScaleY = 1.0;
      }
      else
        {
            // keeping aspect ratio the same
            if (img.Width / img.Height > originalAspectRatio)
            {
                // taking height into consideration
                PageScale.ScaleY = img.Height / originalHeight;
                PageScale.ScaleX = PageScale.ScaleY;
            }
            else
            {
                //taking width into consideration
                PageScale.ScaleX = img.Width / originalWidth;
                PageScale.ScaleY = PageScale.ScaleX;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but doesn't `Stretch` dependency property of the `Image` control work for you? You have a choice of 4 variants of stretching: `Fill`, `None`, `Uniform` and `UniformToFill`. I guess some of these should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @haspermulator said, you can probably just use the Stretch property on the Image control.

```
   <Image Source='logo.png'
           Stretch='UniformToFill' />
```

Both the **Uniform** or **UniformToFill** settings keep the original image aspect ratio.

From [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.stretch.aspx).

- None

  - The content preserves its original size.
- Fill

  - The content is resized to fill the destination dimensions. The aspect ratio is not preserved.
- Uniform

  - The content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio.
- UniformToFill

  - The content is resized to fill the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio of the destination rectangle differs from the source, the source content is clipped to fit in the destination dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might want for

```
double originalHeight = 500;
double originalWidth  = 1000;

double originalHeight = 100;
double originalWidth  = 150;
```

instead. And for

```
if (img.Width < originalWidth || img.Height < originalHeight)

if (!(img.Width > originalWidth) && !(img.Height > originalHeight))
```

instead.

Does this solve your problem?